# Convert .txt file from CRLF to LF and back

Tags: c++, newline, txt

I want to write a little function that takes a file as input, and writes to an output file with the following changes:

- If the input file uses CRLF (`\r\n`) as EndOfLine, it should be replaced with only LF (`\n`).
- If it uses LF (`\n`), those should be replaced with CRLF (`\r\n`)

See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/294219/) for a bit more info on this.

Here's my attempt at doing this:

```cpp
bool convertFile(string location) {
    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    input.open(location); 

    if(!input.is_open()){
        cout << "Invalid location!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    int dot = location.find_last_of('.');
    if(dot != string::npos) location.replace(dot, 1, "_new.");
    output.open(location);


    char c;
    for(;;){
        input.get(c);
        if(!input.good()){
            if(input.eof()) return true;
            else return false;
        } 
        if(c == '\r'){
            input.get(c); 
            if(c == '\n') output << '\n'; // \r\n -> \n
            else output << '\r' << c; // leave as it was, I dont know if this is needed
        } else if (c == '\n'){
            output << "\r\n"; // \n -> \r\n
        } else {
            output << c;
        }
    }
```

However, that doesn't work as expected.

With this input:

[image: input]

I get this output:

[image: output]

I tried solving this by debugging my script, and what I found is that `if(c == '\r')` never evaluates to true, so it seems like I have no `\r`'s in my `.txt`, which Notepad++ says I do.

I am on Windows, and that's the only thing I can think of that might cause this, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open a file in text mode, the input stream will already convert line endings. Open the file in binary mode if you want full control.

```
input.open(location, std::ios::binary);
output.open(location, std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: Great, this works!
But I still don't understand why the ```if(c == '\r')``` was never hit in my code. I'm on windows, so input.open() should have still resulted in ```\r\n``` as EOL, right?

Comment: @MarcMiller: in text mode, `\r\n` will be converted to `\n` while reading. When writing, `\n` will be converted to `\r\n`.